# WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring-mvc, post

I have a simple controller with a POST and GET request

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class UserRegistrationController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm() {

        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        System.out.println("**** UserRegistrationController  GET    ****");
        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        return "register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/registerNewUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerNewUser() {

        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        System.out.println("**** UserRegistrationController POST    ****");
        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        return "register";
    }
}
```

I'm calling it with postman. The post endpoint does not work. I get:
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported

Here is the curl from postman

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:28080/auther/registerNewUser \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 6bb6ef17-1baf-423e-bbec-15713468ff09' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

Do I need to configure something to allow post requests to this controller?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It wouldn't work with Curl without a csrf token.